# Подключение по WAMP protocol с помощью WampSharp

Tags: c#, websocket, wamp-server

Пробую насроить прослушку сообщений биржи Poloniex (API: https://poloniex.com/support/api/)

Написал такое приложение:

```
using System;
using WampSharp.V2;
using WampSharp.V2.Client;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DefaultWampChannelFactory factory =
                new DefaultWampChannelFactory();

            const string serverAddress = "wss://api.poloniex.com";

            IWampChannel channel =
                factory.CreateJsonChannel(serverAddress, "realm1");

            channel.Open().Wait(5000);

            IWampRealmProxy realmProxy = channel.RealmProxy;

            int received = 0;
            IDisposable subscription = null;

            subscription =
                realmProxy.Services.GetSubject<int>("api.poloniex.com/ticker")
                     .Subscribe(x =>
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("Got Event: " + x);

                         received++;

                         if (received > 5)
                         {
                             Console.WriteLine("Closing ..");
                             subscription.Dispose();
                         }
                     });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Не получается открыть канал, ошибка 403 Forbiden.

Где я почему запрещает?

Comment: Вероятно, дело в этом: тута так `serverAddress = "wss://api.poloniex.com";`, а здесь почему-то так `.GetSubject<int>("api.poloniex.com/ticker")`, может должно быть `.GetSubject<int>("ticker")` ?

Comment: @Bulson, дело в том что до этой части кода не доходит, сообщение получаю на этапе создания канала  `channel.Open().Wait(5000)`

Comment: А если работать через Public API Methods, то по крайней мере returnTicker отдает информацию. Если надо могу показать в ответе, что я написал.

Comment: @Bulson, я вот тоже набросал апи, но и тут 403.  https://github.com/RomanTymokhov/PoloTestConnection/tree/feature/tohoff82